# Problem when deploying React app to GitHub pages

Tags: reactjs, deployment, github-pages

I have a problem when I try to deploy my react app to GitHub pages, it shows an empty page, blank.
in my GitHub, I see some files but not the source itself.
I used yarn to deploy.
here is the package.json file:

```
  "name": "monsters-relodex",
  "homepage": "https://eliranma.github.io/monster-rolodex",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "gh-pages": "^3.1.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "yarn build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -b master -d build"

  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Could it have something to do with name spelled wrong? "name": "monsters-relodex". Should be rolodex

Comment: checked 4 hours for misspelling, everything match.

Comment: Are you saying you don't have misspelling?  Look at first line of your script. Name has relodex instead of rolodex

Comment: I said everything to match, because the misspelling was in purpose

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

this `"deploy": "gh-pages -b master -d build"`

to `"deploy": "gh-pages -d build"`

if the problem still exists, I think the problem is that you don't have the actual sourcecode on your your master branch. Commit the code (the src folder) itself on the master branch and try again.

Comment: I think I'm doing something wrong because you right, I cant see my src folder, I tried to commit it to git but I still can't see it.

Comment: I uploaded the src folder to GitHub manually and it works fine.
I tried to understand what I did wrong, I did `git add` and `git commit`

Comment: https://github.com/KDSGYT/subsCount-react Your repository is supposed to look like this.

Comment: master branch: The source code all the folders package.json or any other file goes here:    gh-pages branch:  when you run the `npm run deploy` in yout terminal. npm will automatically make a build folder and that folder will be deployed automatically  to the gh-pages branc.

Comment: https://github.com/eliranma/monster-rolodex
it looks different how did you do it?

Comment: You need to initalize the repository in the root folder. The folder that contains all the files of your project.

Comment: Then you make a commit there to the repo\

Comment: Exactly what I did first time, can you please give me a short step by step commands guide